# Why do I get a -1 if I downvote an answer?

Tags: support, reputation

I've noticed for the past few months on Stack Overflow that whenever I downvote an answer, I receive a -1 in my reputation. I just don't understand why this thing keeps happening. What is the actual reason for me getting a -1? Is it some sort of a 'revenge' by the user whose answer I have downvoted? Or is it something else?

Comment: p.s., still worth mentioning, you _won't_ get a -1 if you downvote a question. So please, if you come across a seriously awful question, downvote it and _don't_ feel bad about it.

Comment: Sometimes I feel it should work both ways as it seems I'm penalizing myself for trying to help make this site better by downvoting an answer but then there are horrible questions and no penalization for a downvoted question. I think I'd feel better if I downvoted an answer and I got -1 but the answer got -5 or something worse.

Comment: @Diemuzi: When you downvote an answer, you lose 1 reputation and the person whose answer you downvoted loses 2 reputation. So you: -1, other person: -2.

Comment: Of course, that was clear from the start. But I was trying to point out that the penalty for a downvote should be greater for both questions and answers for the person asking/answering. I wouldn't mind the -1 as much at that point.

Comment: Why is it new users never read the [help] to find out how reputation works but never asks or complains about getting + reputation but always manages to ask and complain about - rep? Your first stop when you have a question about how SO works should be the [help], in this case [What is reputation? How do I gain (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), clearly listed in the [help] index.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is intentional, and it's part of the design of the system. It is not someone revenge downvoting you. See *[How does “Reputation” work? - You lose reputation when...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/213963)* and *[Why do you lose reputation for down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/213963)* (and the linked questions on the sidebar) on Meta.SE.

Consider it an investment into the quality of the site. By downvoting things, you help send a signal that the material isn't up to the quality you desire. If the post is ultimately deleted, you will get the reputation back.

Comment: +1'd this answer, but I think it does not really defend against revenge downvotes. People still get a lot of them since it only costs -1.

Comment: I think the design is not bad, but truth must prevail. So the question is: Who will delete it and when?

Answer (score 24):

Extractions from links posted by MichaelT:

The motivation behind it is to put emphasis on upvoting or not voting at all. This way, downvotes will carry more weight, and it will also prevent users from abusing the system by downvoting excessively.

According to what Jeff/Joel discussed on the Stack Overflow podcast, they wanted to find a way to discourage users from downvoting for less legitimate reasons (say a pro-Java developer downvoting everything remotely related to .NET or the like).

While we value good questions (and asking a great question is absolutely an art), we want to explicitly encourage people to provide the best possible answers. Without people interested in providing good answers, the questions are moot. We know that answers have more intrinsic value than questions, and the reputation balance should reflect that.

To put it another way, when I go to a Stack Exchange home page, I see a list of questions. If most of those are terrible questions with little to no indication that I’d be wasting my time by reading them, the value proposition of visiting and participating is diminished: I have better things to do.

Compare that to answers on a specific question: I’ve made a conscious choice to look into what I think is an interesting question. I already made the decision that the question is worth my time. If I find the answers to be useless, I have a few different options, as an interested party, to register my displeasure, including writing my own answer. Being able to write your own answer is key: if your answer is good enough, it’ll rise above the junk answers and everyone will be better off for it.

Comment: I have been reviewing some Late Answers. Realistically the only sensible action I can take on some of them (given my current rep level) is a downvote (plus, almost always, a comment). I am not usually precious about my rep level, but I really object to losing points in this situation. I'm absolutely not preparing alternative answers in these cases (there's usually a perfectly good accepted answer anyway).