# Summary of downvoted answers which have changed and are not deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, downvotes

We have a -1 penalty for downvoting answers. From [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272551/2441442):

> Consider it an investment into the quality of the site. By downvoting
>   things, you help send a signal that the material isn't up to the
>   quality you desire. If the post is ultimately deleted, you will get
>   the reputation back.

Based on this, it would be nice to have a summary page that shows us all the answers we've downvoted which have changed and are not deleted.

This would give us the ability to review our downvotes. If the quality of an answer has changed positively, we could decide to change our downvote.

Comment: VERY related: [Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content).  Not quite a duplicate because this feature-request asks for a summary page instead of a notification.

Comment: @ryanyuyu "Not quite a duplicate" -- Indeed. From the point of view of the downvoter, a summary page is much better than a notification because it is less intrusive.

Comment: I think that the only sane way to do this is to allows /users/current?tab=votes to be ordered by activity.

Comment: @Braiam: you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote ? Afaik, deleted posts are already excluded…

Comment: @Holger no, like in the search https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aq basically, it orders the items based on latest action on the whole question (new answer, edit, etc.)

Comment: For now, you can use SOX, which has many useful features, including a notification upon editing content you’ve downvoted: http://stackapps.com/q/6091/34727. (no affiliation)

Comment: Cross-site dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab (disclosure: my answer contains a userscript that implements such a summary page).