# Why wasn't this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, automatic-deletion

[This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339034/summary-of-downvoted-answers-which-have-changed-and-are-not-deleted/) inspired me to look at my downvotes to see if I should reverse any of them. While reviewing my downvotes I came upon this question: [CSS doesn't seem to work in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094668/css-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-php/36094745)

It seems to fit the third set of conditions from https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

All of these conditions have been met but it hasn't been deleted and the question was posted last March. Why hasn't it been deleted?

Comment: Jeez, who wrote that Help page and why did they use `code` formatting for `numerical` values that are `not` actually code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't fit the first rule of that set:

> *"If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ..."*

It's not closed.